# Why do we need the removing-whitespace tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, burninate-request

If you look at the questions in [removing-whitespace](/questions/tagged/removing-whitespace), most of them also have the [whitespace](/questions/tagged/whitespace) tag.  Also, we have the [symbols](/questions/tagged/symbols) tag, but that doesn't mean we should have a [removing-symbols](/questions/tagged/removing-symbols) tag.  I mean, if this made sense, we might as well also have the [adding-whitespace](/questions/tagged/adding-whitespace) tag, too.  I think the [removing-whitespace](/questions/tagged/removing-whitespace) tag should be burninated, why do we have it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no good in keeping both [removing-whitespace](/questions/tagged/removing-whitespace) and [whitespace](/questions/tagged/whitespace) tag. They are useless. Only 2 users has 10 answers in whitespace tag, most only 1-2. My proposal is to remove both not just one.